# How to rotate compressed log file on centos 7?

Tags: logging, log-files, logrotate, kafka, log-rotation

I have customized kafka server and the app is creating log files and configures log rotation. My problem is that I need to compress the rotation logs that were created.

I tried to create new log rotation file on /etc/logrotate.d with the following configuration:

```
/opt/kafka/logs/server.log.* {

  monthly

  compress

  dateext

  dateformat _%Y-%m-%d

  extension .tar.gz

  missingok

  ifempty

}
```

With this configuration I cannot compress my old files, and the message is:
log does not need rotating (log has been already rotated).

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Perhaps https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15546/logrotate-log-does-not-need-rotating-why will help? Try to Google the error message first, to show you did some research prior to posting.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following configs:

General logs files:

```
/var/log/kafka/*.log
{
    daily
    dateext
    dateformat _%Y-%m-%d-%s
    compress
    nodelaycompress
    nocopy
    nocopytruncate
    nocreate
    missingok
    notifempty
}
```

Logs generates by log4j

```
/var/log/kafka/*.log*[0-9][0-9]
{
    daily
    # remove after compressed
    rotate 0
    nodateext
    compress
    nodelaycompress
    nocopy
    nocopytruncate
    nocreate

    missingok
    notifempty
}
```

Change the frequency as you need